# Learning python after using java for a while, why isn't my "stutter" function for Linked Lists working?

Tags: python, linked-list

so as the title states I'm learning python, and I figured a great way would be to play around with linked lists. I am trying to make a "stutter" function, which basically takes every integer in the linked list, and repeats it however many times you tell it to repeat.

For example: If my linked list is 1->2->3 and n  = 3, the new linked list should be 1->1->1->2->2->2->3->3->3.

My code for the function is:

```
def stutterNL(self, n):
    current = self.head
    next = current.next

    while current != None:

        for i in range(n - 1):
            current.next = Node(current.data)

        current.next = next
        current = next
        if next != None:
            next = next.next

    return self.head
```

My node class is:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

and my linked list class and constructor are:

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you for any help you can provide, learning python has been tricky

Comment: What is your code doing instead?

Comment: Not updating the linked list at all, my apologies I should have mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, you just need to make sure to keep updating `current` to point to `current.next` at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop:

```
def stutterNL(self, n):
    current = self.head
    next = current.next

    while current != None:

        for i in range(n - 1):
            current.next = Node(current.data)
            current = current.next

        current.next = next
        current = next
        if next != None:
            next = next.next

    return self.head
```

Comment: I knew you would think that when you saw it :-) Hope you have a lot of fun with Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple "currents" in your for loop and not linking them. You try to link them outside the for loop but by that time some have disappeared.  Also another advise would be to change names to make it easy for you and for others. Maybe something like 'next_node' or something